# Как вывести данные за период (текущий месяц+ Прошлый) Oracle

Tags: oracle

Как вывести данные за текущий месяц и прошлый. База данных Oracle.
То есть если сегодня 18.02.2021 вывести за январь и за февраль до 18.02.2021

Например сегодня 05.02.2022. Тогда вывести за прошлый месяц(01.01.2022 по 05.02.2022)

Comment: За текущий год.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.